# how to sort list of hashmaps

Tags: java, collections

I have a `List` of `HashMap` such as below

```
ArrayList l = new ArrayList ();
HashMap m = new HashMap ();
m.add("site_code","AL");
m.add("site_name","Apple");
l.add(m);
m = new HashMap();
m.add("site_code","JL");
m.add("site_name","Cat");
l.add(m);
m = new HashMap();
m.add("site_code","PL");
m.add("site_name","Banana");
l.add(m)
```

I'd like to sort the `list` based on `site_name`. So in the end it would be sorted as.

```
Apple, Banana, Cat
```

I was trying something like this:

```
Collections.sort(l, new Comparator(){
           public int compare(HashMap one, HashMap two) {
              //what goes here?
           }
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you make your collections generic, it will end up looking about like this:

```
Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>(){ 
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> one, HashMap<String, String> two) { 
            return one.get("site_name").compareTo(two.get("site_name"));
        } 
});
```

If you can't use generics because you're stuck on a 1.4 or earlier platform, then you'll have to cast the `get`'s to `String`.

(Also, as a matter of style, I'd prefer declaring the variables as `List` and `Map` rather than `ArrayList` and `HashMap`. But that's not relevant to the question.)

Comment: And if you want to do it reverse order (descending) try something like this: 
Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>(){ 
        public int compare(HashMap<String, String> one, HashMap<String, String> two) {   
            String s1 = one.get("site_name");
            String s2 = two.get("site_name");
            if(s1 == s2) return 0;
            if(s1 > s2) return -1; 
            return 1;
           
        } 
});

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a great time to think about a redesign.  From your example, it looks like all of your objects have the same two fields - `site_name` and `site_code`.  In that case, why not define your own class rather than using a `HashMap`?

```
public class Site implements Comparable<Site> {
    private String site_name;
    private String site_code;

    // getters and setters, equals, and hashCode

    public int compareTo(Site other) {
        return this.site_name.compareTo(other.getSiteName);
    }
}
```

And then you can just use `Collections.sort()`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
String codeOne = (String)one.get("site_code");
String codeTwo = (String)two.get("site_code");

return codeOne.compareTo(codeTwo);
```

I haven't compiled or tested this, but it should be along these lines.

Comment: (just beaten by mmyers - definitely go for their generics based answer).